# How do I censor certain words and return with "CENSORED" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get certain words censored from an array in Ruby and have been having difficulty doing so. I have managed to censor some words but then when I try censor all the banned phrases, either the punctuation goes missing or the words that have a punctuation don't get censored.

```
test_tweets = [
  "This president sucks!",
  "I hate this Blank House!",
  "I can't believe we're living under such bad leadership. We were so foolish",
  "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad -- it sucks."
  ]
banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]



   censored_tweets = []

index = 0

test_tweets.each do |tweet|
  censored_tweets[index] = [] if censored_tweets[index] == nil
  tweet.split(/\W+/).each do |word|
    banned_phrases.include?(word) ? 
    censored_tweets[index].push("CENSORED") : censored_tweets[index].push(word)
  end
  censored_tweets[index] = censored_tweets[index].join(" ")
  index += 1
end

puts censored_tweets
```

This method censors all the banned phrases but removes the punctuation. Could someone help as this has been such an undoable task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular Expression is nice for this. Regexps are very powerful but not always easy. This one however is easy to construct:

```
test_tweets = [
    "This president sucks!",
    "I hate this Blank House!",
    "I can't believe we're living under such bad leadership. We were so foolish",
    "President Presidentname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad -- it sucks."
    ]
 banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]

 regex_banned =  Regexp.union( banned_phrases) #that's all there is to it
 censored_tweets = test_tweets.map{|tweet| tweet.gsub(regex_banned, "CENSORED") }
  
 puts censored_tweets
```

Comment: A step in the right direction, but needs tweaking :) `"I like badminton".gsub(regex_banned, "CENSORED") # => "I like CENSOREDminton"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: That reminds me of that time when conservative US websites were celebrating the gold medals of US sprinter [*Tyson Homosexual*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyson_Gay). See also the [*Scunthorpe Problem*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Yes, yes. You can't get this right and that is a very good thing.